# Print a paragraph using some of the dictionary values

Tags: python

The code below is my program. I want to print the outcome more user-friendly like, "Here is your forecast for New York. Expect cloudy conditions with temperatures topping out at 24 degrees. Winds will be……". I tried several methods but seemed to fail by each one. The best I got was printing it as a list. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

```
    #declare cities and their weather for the program
    city_1 = {'city name':'New York', 'city_zip':'10001', 'forecast_temp':24, 'forecast_condition':'cloudy', 'forecast_wind_direction':'north', 'forecast_wind_speed':13, 'forecast_precip':'sleet'}
    
    city_2 = {'city_name' : 'Chicago', 'city_zip' : '60007', 'forecast_temp' : 45, 'forecast_condition' : 'fog', 'forecast_wind_direction': 'east', 'forecast_wind_speed': 10, 'forecast_precip': 'rain' }
    
    city_3 = {'city_name' : 'Miami', 'city_zip' : '33101', 'forecast_temp' : 77, 'forecast_condition' : 'sunny', 'forecast_wind_direction': 'south', 'forecast_wind_speed': 12, 'forecast_precip': 'none' }
    
    def userLocation(): #get city from user
        """Get location from user."""
        location = ""
        while location != ("") or location != ("q"):#program does not have valid city yet
            location = input("Enter the zip code or city that you want to get the weather for: \nEnter 'q' to quit.\n")
            if location.lower() == "new york" or location == "10001":
                city = city_1
                break
            elif location.lower() == "chicago" or location == "60007":
                city = city_2
                break
            elif location.lower == "miami" or location == "33101":
                city = city_3
                break
            elif location.lower() == "q":#user wants to quit program
                exit()
        return city
    
    def printInfo(city): #print weather information to user for specified city
        """Print weather information about specific city."""
        print ('\n'.join("{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in city.items()))
    
    print ("Hello, I will be giving you the weather for any zip code or city that you want!")
city = userLocation()
printInfo (city)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
def printInfo(city): #print weather information to user for specified city
    """Print weather information about specific city."""
    starters = ["Here is your forecast for ", ". Expect ", " conditions with temperatures topping out at ", " degrees. Winds will be coming in from the ", " at speeds of about ", " mph. The forecast precipitation is most likely "]
    order = ["city_name","forecast_condition","forecast_temp","forecast_wind_direction","forecast_wind_speed","forecast_precip"]
    output = ""
    for i in range(len(starters)):
      output += starters[i]
      output += str(city.get(order[i]))
    print(output + ".")
```

Output:

```
Here is your forecast for New York. Expect cloudy conditions with temperatures topping out at 24 degrees. Winds will be coming in from the north at speeds of about 13 mph. The forecast precipitation is most likely sleet.
```

Note: I noticed a typo in your declaration for `city_1`, you forgot the underscore in `city_name`.

This code has a list of starters and the order of keys, and the for loop simply concatenates them to an output. We can use the `.get()` function to retrieve the value to a given key of a dictionary.

I hope this helped answer your question! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Answer (score 0):

If the keys in the dictionary are always the same, you could try a formatted string:

print(f'Here is your forecast for {city["city_name"]}. Expect {city["forecast_condition"]} conditions with temperatures topping out at {city["forecast_temp"]} degrees.')

Comment: Thanks, though I am having difficulties extracting the information as the object is named "city" in the print statement though the declaring is for three different city objects and in a different function.

Comment: Maybe try reading up on python namespaces to prevent unreadable code. Also this program is perfect for functional programming (everything is a function. A function only knows its arguments. A function will always generate the same output for the same input).